{NiceTabular} - Automatic Vertical Spacing in Cells
I'm currently trying my best to set up a user manual for a system. It's working fine, except I'm continuously running into the same issue when trying to set up tables.
I'd like to generate a table with three columns, the first of which naming a function, the second one describing it and the last one naming examples of features and so.
As the last of the columns might display several examples I will need more rows for that.
I've tried solving that in the tabularx - environment with multicolumn and multirow commands, but I wasn't really successful.
Now I've tried utilizing the NiceTabular-environment, which actually works. There's just a minor flaw I really can't get around:
\documentclass[10pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
            \begin{NiceTabular}{XXX}[hvlines]
                    Function: & Description & Features:\\
                    \Block[l]{*-1}{Compensation Function:} & \Block[l]{*-1}{Compensates for various grid perturbations and changes $cos\varphi$} & steplessly available\\
                    && customizable and so\\
                \end{NiceTabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}

If the middle column exceeds the height of the adjacent columns (I guess the same will happen for the first / third one), the text simply doesn't wrap properly but exceeds the cell's vertical limits. I wasn't able to find a solution (in the NiceMatrix manual) for that as I'm not really sure how to verbalize the problem.
Maybe someone can help me with that.
Sorry if information is missing. It'y my very first post on here.
Thanks in advance!

I'm not quite sure about that. There is an automatic line break. The problem is rather that the text block eventually becomes larger than the cell.

The commands \Block of nicematrix don't create space (except the mono-row blocks which create vertical space and the mono-column blocks which create horizontal space). You should try the package tabularray which is able to address that kind of problem.

Not related: You should write $\cos\varphi$ instead of $cos\varphi$.

The commands \Block of nicematrix don't create space (except the mono-row blocks which create vertical space and the mono-column blocks which create horizontal space). You should try the package tabularray which is able to address that kind of problem.
However, if you want to use nicematrix, you should give more space to the second column, for example with the following code:
\documentclass[10pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{NiceTabular}{lXV[l]{5cm}}[hvlines]
  Function: & Description & Features:\\
  \Block[l]{*-1}{Compensation\\ Function:} 
   & \Block[l]{*-1}{Compensates for various grid perturbations and changes $\cos\varphi$} 
   & steplessly available\\
  && customizable and so\\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}

If the content of a cell is wider than 5 cm, it will be wrapped.

\begin{center}
\begin{NiceTabular}{lXV[l]{5cm}}[hvlines]
  Function: & Description & Features:\\
  \Block[l]{*-1}{Compensation\\ Function:} 
   & \Block[l]{*-1}{Compensates for various grid perturbations and changes $\cos\varphi$} 
   & the content of that cell has been increased \\
  && customizable and so\\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}


